# paste several column values into one value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pasting

I have a really simple question that I cannot find a straightforward answer for. I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
df3 <- data.frame(x=c(1:10),y=c(5:14),z=c(25:34))

ID  x  y  z
1   1  5 25
2   2  6 26
3   3  7 27
etc.
```

And I want to 'paste' together the different values in each column so that they form a single, combined value, as in:

```
ID x+y+z
1  1525
2  2626
3  3727
```

I'm sure that this is very easy to do, but I just don't know how!

Comment: BTW -- I reformatted your question. If you want to learn how to do that, click on the `edit` button at the bottom of your question, and look at the format I used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep, `paste()` is *exactly* what you want to do:

```
 df3$xyz <- with(df3, paste(x,y,z, sep=""))

 # Or, if you want the result to be numeric, rather than character
 df3$xyz <- as.numeric(with(df3, paste(x,y,z, sep="")))
```